# Doubt in Equations of motion of rigid body, can anyone tell me how the second step occurred from first one

Tags: classical-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, rigid-body-dynamics

[image: Doubt in Equations of motion of rigid body, can anyone tell me how the second step occurred from first one.]

Doubt in Equations of motion of rigid body, can anyone tell me how the second step occurred from first one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To me it looks like there might be a misprint. Easier to go straight from the first line. All it's doing is writing out the cross product explicitly:
$$
(\omega \times J)_x = (\omega \times (I\cdot\omega))_x = \omega_y (I\cdot\omega)_z - \omega_z(I\cdot\omega)_y
$$
Hope that helps!

Comment: hi, thanks for clarifying. could u explain about the formula and how the x coordinates changes to y and z coordinates

Comment: In a cross-product, the $x$ component of the cross product $a \times b$ is $a_y b_z - a_z b_y$

Comment: oh ok that's the formula, thank u so much Robbie

Comment: I agree the 1st step has incorrect notation. You don't take the _x_ component of $\omega$ and multiply it with the _x_ component of $J$. You need the _x_ component of the resulting cross product as @Robbie showed here.

Answer (score 0):

The answer @Robbie posted is the correct one. I wanted to add a helpful tweak to the cross product which might help you understand how to get to step 2

When you have a cross-product such as $\vec{\omega} \times \vec{J}$ you can treat it like a matrix/vector product by defining the following skew-symmetric 3×3 matrix

$$ \vec{\omega} \times = \begin{vmatrix} 0 & -\omega_z & \omega_y
\\ \omega_z & 0 & -\omega_x \\ -\omega_y & \omega_x & 0 \end{vmatrix} $$

in your case $\vec{\omega} \times \mathrm{I}\, \vec{\omega}$ expands out using the rules of linear algebra as

$$ \begin{vmatrix} 0 & -\omega_z & \omega_y
\\ \omega_z & 0 & -\omega_x \\ -\omega_y & \omega_x & 0 \end{vmatrix} \begin{vmatrix} I_x & & \\ & I_y & \\ & & I_z \end{vmatrix} \begin{vmatrix} \omega_x \\ \omega_y \\ \omega_x \end{vmatrix} 
= \begin{vmatrix} \omega_y \omega_z (I_z - I_y) \\
 \omega_z \omega_x (I_x - I_z) \\ \omega_x \omega_y (I_y - I_x) \\   \end{vmatrix} $$

Comment: Hi, thanks for your explanation. I want to know about that skew-symmetric matrix and why we considered that ω as such matrix.

Comment: @Sai - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skew-symmetric_matrix#Cross_product

Comment: @Sai - https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2248459/3301

Comment: @Sai the matrix form of the cross product is very convenient for computer programming and equation development.